# screen flicker after hwe kernel upgrade

Tags: kernel, screen, flicker

After I performed an hwe kernel update (to 5.3.0-28-generic) on my Thinkpad T480s running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Im experiencing an occasional screen flicker.
Its really just a very short 1ms blink of the screen, it doesn't cause any crashes or other problems, it just happens all of a sudden and unexpectedly.

Being on AC or battery doesn't seem to make a different, and same with having external monitor plugged in or not.

Has anyone experienced a something similar or has an idea how to solve this non-urgent, but annoying bug?

The output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2257
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

The output of `sudo modprobe nvidia`: nothing

I noticed that being in Intel mode (energy saving mode) the flickering occurs, while it doesn't occur if I'm in Nvidia mode (performance mode).

**EDIT 1:**
I recently updated to Ubuntu 19.10. and since then the problem has vanished!

**EDIT 2:**
I need to correct that with Ubuntu 19.10. the flicker still exists, but occurs a lot less often.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: What is the driver you installed? It doesn't load. See the updated answer.

Comment: Now all looks good. I have no more ideas.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for your help so far! I appreciate it

Comment: I noticed that being in Intel mode (energy saving mode) the flickering occurs, while it doesn't occur if I'm in Nvidia mode (performance mode)